# UIPageViewController - start not at the beginning, but in the middle (page 2)

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

I have set up a `PageViewController` with three pages. However, I want it to start at page 2 (in the middle). But I don't know how to do this.

I know you set the start `viewController` like this:

```
pageViewController.setViewControllers([viewControllerAtIndex(startIndex)!], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

But you can only say `direction` `forward` or `reverse`. But in this case, it's both.

What can I do? Thank you!

Comment: There is property in UIPageControll : pages.you can set current page

Comment: is this a property of the `pageViewController`? I can't find it

Comment: So, I found the property but it's not changing anything. Also, I think the page control is separated from the pageViewController (I think)

Comment: Try yourPageName.currentPage = {YourPageNumber} this will do the job. Tested and it worked....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your implementation for the startViewController is correct

```
pageViewController.setViewControllers([viewControllerAtIndex(startIndex)!], direction: .forward, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

In your UIPageViewControllerDataSource implementation, also implement this method:

```
func presentationIndex(for pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
    return startIndex
}
```

You might also need

```
func presentationCount(for pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
    return pageData.count
}
```

Comment: Not quite. Since this where he wants to start, `animated` should be `false`.